# Partial internet connectivity on Android device but device connected through hotspot has internet

Tags: wifi-hotspot, data-connection

I have a xiamoi mi5 which is hosting a mobile hotspot, and a laptop which is connected to this hotspot.

- On the android device, I cannot connect to the internet. Most Apps see that I am offline.
- Interestingly speedtest, whatsapp, facebook and playstore have internet access
- On the laptop everything is fine.

I made sure I didn't have incorrect APN settings, and the one I have match the official.

How can I get full internet connectivity on my mobile?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226241

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the sim card loading two APN entries, one marked by the phone as *"MMS"* and the other marked *"General"* . After deleting the MMS APN entry, all phone applications now have full internet connectivity.

Personally I cannot explain the source of this confusion.

Comment: Loading MMS APN is normal behaviour, but why would apps _use_ it instead of the normal one? In the APN list, do you have selection markers alongside the APN entries? Is the General one selected?