# Wi-Fi hotspot and internet connection

Tags: huawei, wifi-hotspot, tethering

I bought a few days ago a Hauwei P30 lite, which comes with Android 9.
In my case, I often connect to the Internet via the mobile network. When I configure the smartphone as a Wi-Fi hotspot (tethering), the smartphone apps are not allowed any more to the Internet (while the external devices exploiting that same hotspot for Internet connection are). In other words, If I use the smartphone as a mobile 4G+ modem, then no Android app has Internet connection.
For example, after enabling the hotspot, my laptop connects flawlessly to the Internet through the smartphone hotspot, so I can open for example WhatsApp web, but I cannot use it because the WhatsApp app on the smartphone is not allowed to the Internet. I find that rather silly.
My old 3G smartphone with Android 4.2.1 provides a hotspot while at the same time allowing Internet navigation from the smartphone, so that the WhatsApp scenario described above works flawlessly.
The new smartphone with a 4G+ modem does not allow that. ????
For the record, I am settled in Italy.

Comment: it may caused by provider not allowing you to share mobile data which is controlled by APN settings in your Huawei device https://www.groovypost.com/howto/hide-data-usage-get-truly-unlimited-tethering-tmobile-one

Answer (score 2):

Well, one of the system updates has upgraded my smartphone OS from Android 9 to 10.
And that has fixed the problem.
Now my smartphone can work flawlessly at the same time as a Wi-Fi hotspot for external devices while maintaining Internet connection for itself.
Well done! I hope some of the next system updates will not revert the situation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Huawei/comments/8w82fj/huawei_p20_lite_cant_use_phone_internet_while) user PiGeek_314

> Go into Settings > Wireless & Networks > Mobile Network > Access Point Name > and Delete the "Hotspot APN"

or this for AT&T

- Enable developer mode (Go to Settings -> System -> About phone, and click on the build number until the developer mode is enabled).
- Enable USB debugging under Settings -> System -> Developer options
- Connect the device with a USB cable to a computer with the Android SDK [platform tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) installed
- Start an adb shell
  In the adb shell, type the following:

  ```
  adb shell 
  settings put global tether_dun_required 0 
  settings put global tether_dun_apn "APNDUN,n.ispsn,,,,,,http://mmsc.mobile.att.net,proxy.mobile.att.net,80,310,410,,default,dun,mms,supl,hipri,fota,xcap"
  ```

another method is to edit `build.prop`

```
net.tethering.noprovisioning=true
```

Note: you need a rooted device for this

I am not sure how this solves your problem with losing internet connection. i have just copy & pasted this. other Huawei users claim this works. basically reason could be that different APNs exist and device (or just the app) is choosing the wrong entry

Comment: Interesting answer, however it does not solve my problem.
I do not have a tethering data limit problem.
My problem is that I cannot use my smartphone to navigate in the Internet while tethering is active.

Comment: yes i understood that issue, that's what other Huawei users claim too. some say slight different (some apps have access while most others don't have connection) and the above solution should fix some routing issue in AOSP build is translating the hotspot APN properly but not sending device data to phone APN. of course it depends on carrier. i have just googled this with keywords *"Huawei+tethering+no+connection"* maybe you should do your own research